# How can I convert two python lists into a dictionary correctly?

Tags: python, pymssql

I am trying to convert two lists into one dictionary to update my database.

The first list contains the URLs of HTML files and the second list contains the HTML files itself.

When tyring to convert this I getting this result:

{'file:/C:/1456110874625203.html': '[', 'file:/C:/1456111318575265.html': "'"}

Instead of this result:

{'file:/C:/1456110874625203.html': "Hello, this is a HTML File without tags", 'file:/C:/1456111318575265.html': "Hello, this is a HTML File without tags"}

So instead of getting the whole HTML file into the dictionary I am getting just the start of the list (the square bracket '[' and the last part of the list (the quoute "'").

How can I get the whole file into the dictionary?

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import re
import pandas as pd
import itertools 
from collections.abc import Iterable
import pymssql



conn = pymssql.connect(
    host='x',
    port=x,
    user='x',
    password='x',
    database='x'
)
cursor = conn.cursor() 
cursor.execute('SELECT x FROM x')

text = [r[0] for r in cursor.fetchall() ]

conn.close()


conn = pymssql.connect(
    host='x',
    port=x,
    user='x',
    password='x',
    database='x'
)
cursor = conn.cursor() 
cursor.execute('SELECT x FROM x')

t = [r[0] for r in cursor.fetchall() ]

conn.close()


text1 = str(text)
soup = bs(text1, 'html.parser')
autor = soup.get_text()


s = autor.replace('\\n', '')


dictw = dict(zip(t,s))

print (dictw)
```

Comment: Can you print s and t alone directly after assignment?

Comment: Yes I can print it.

Comment: Can you post the results?